# Chi Squared test failing

Tags: r

I'm getting the following error when I try to do a chi squared test for independence

> Error in chisq.test(cont_counts_combined) : all entries of 'x' must be nonnegative and finite

This is what my data look like.  I reshaped this from data from long to wide and then combined variables (4 variables (low, med, high, very high) down to 2 (`lowandmed` & `highandvhigh`) Is there a problem with my formatting?

[image]

I want to ask if each continent has the same distribution of counts in `LowandMed` vs `HighandVHigh` as null hypothesis or if they some have more in `lowandmed` or `highandvhigh`.

Thanks for any advice :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chisq.test()` doesn't know what to do with the first column of `cont_counts_combined`. Try `chisq.test(cont_counts_combined[, -1])`.

See `?chisq.test` under "Details" for details.